# Set HTML as text in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write script to update some html text to new text. However I get error:

> SQL Error [42725]: ERROR: operator is not unique: unknown / unknown
>   Hint: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   Position: 469

Is it because of html tags? What is the right way to do that?

This is my SQL:

```
update messaging.email 
set body='<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="de">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
    text
        <p>
       @TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Model.Timestamp.Value, Model.TimeZoneInfo).ToString("d'/'MM'/'yyyy", Model.CultureInfo)
        </p>


    </body>
</html>' 
where id = 1
```

Apparently the error came from escaping `"d'/'MM'/'yyyy"`. So I changed it to `"d''/''MM''/''yyyy"`

Comment: This should work just fine. What client or API are you using? Is this the actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that your string literal spans multiple lines.  Try using a single line HTML string and it should work:

```
UPDATE messaging.email
SET body = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="de"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title></title></head><body>text<p>Text "@Model.Name"</p></body></html>'
WHERE <some condition>;
```

See for yourself that this works in the demo below.

### Demo